# Making a patent number underage,

Tags: law

I have a friend that has invented an idea but he is under 18,
So can he make a patent number on his name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any age limitations relating to inventorship.  In fact, this FAQ notes a patent was issued to a four-year-old inventor... http://inventors.about.com/library/inventors/blkidprimer2.htm

The bigger issue would likely be assigning the invention in view of limitations on contracting with minors.

Comment: Do you think it will be hard for him to sell the idea?

Comment: This is starting to get outside of my comfort zone, but as I understand it, in most states, minors lack "capacity" (the legal ability) to enter into a binding contract (for things other than necessities).

Comment: The true inventor must be listed. An inventor on a U.S. patent application can also be incarcerated, insane and can be located anywhere in the world. With AIA, an application can now be filed by an "applicant" rather than by the inventor. There might be a subtlety there that helps.